# Why am I getting a does not include static main error in visual studio?

Tags: c#, winforms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXD08.png)

Many of you have probably seen this program before, I'm sorry if this is a very beginner issue. I am getting error cs5001   Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point. I'm not quite sure what to add, can anyone assist me with this, please?

Below is my code, and a screenshot of the window form. Thank you for your time!

```cs
namespace redactedHomework2
{

        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            const double CLASS_A_PRICE = 15;
            const double CLASS_B_PRICE = 12;
            const double CLASS_C_PRICE = 9;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                    double classA, classB, classC;
                    double classArev;
                    double classBrev;
                    double classCrev;
                    double total;

                    classA = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
                    classB = double.Parse(textBox2.Text);
                    classC = double.Parse(textBox3.Text);

                    classArev = classA * CLASS_A_PRICE;
                    classBrev = classB * CLASS_B_PRICE;
                    classCrev = classC * CLASS_C_PRICE;
                    total = classArev + classBrev + classCrev;

                    textBox4.Text = classArev.ToString("c");
                    textBox5.Text = classBrev.ToString("c");
                    textBox6.Text = classCrev.ToString("c");
                    textBox7.Text = total.ToString("c");

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }

        private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "";
            textBox2.Text = "";
            textBox3.Text = "";
            textBox4.Text = "";
            textBox5.Text = "";
            textBox6.Text = "";
            textBox7.Text = "";
        }

        private void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there in your project (solution explorer) the default `Program.cs` with a `Program` class containing the `static Main()`?

Comment: Yes, under the Form1.cs there is a form1designer.cs and form1.resx. Edit, there is not a Program folder

Comment: You said Visual Basic but your code is like C# and you tag the question `c#` (?)

Comment: I talked about the Program.cs, not Form1.cs nor form1designer.cs and form1.resx... If Program.cs with Main is missing, you can add it manually.

Comment: There is not a program.cs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Program.cs is missing, add a new class to the project in the solution explorer and name it "Program.cs".

Right click on the project name > Add > Class.

In it, put this code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace redactedHomework2 
{
  static class Program
  {
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
      Application.EnableVisualStyles();
      Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
      Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
  }
}
```

Check in the project properties that you are in "Windows Application" output type.

Or you can try to add the Main method in your Form1 class directly.

Else you can start a new project in another folder then import your Form1 file.

Comment: You can try to add the Main method in your Form1 class directly. Or you can start a new project in another folder then import your actuel Form1 file.

Comment: I apologize I added it as a new class.

Comment: Now I am getting a Type or namespace definition or end of file expected error.

Comment: Nvm, I figured it out. Extra brace in code. Thank you for your help and time with this solution!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to build a forms application but compile it as a console application. A console application has a static `Main` method which is where control of user code begins.  A forms application does not; forms applications are event based; an event handler executes when a form is loaded.

If you're getting that error while you are trying to build a forms application, you've got your project settings configured wrong. When you start a new application in Visual Studio, make sure to choose a forms-based project template rather than a console-based template.

Comment: Unless things have changed a lot, it’s been a while since I’ve written a forms application, you still need a static main method as an entry point. The project template typically created a program.cs file with the needed `Main` method where it instanced and ran the main form (`Application.Run(new mainForm())`)